Firestore returning undefined when trying to get array field from document
I'm trying to get the players array from this Firestore document you can see in the screenshot, in order to update it with a POST call.
My issue is that whenever I get this document, calling doc.data().players or doc.get("players") is always returning undefined.
When debugging I can see that doc.data() contains all the expected field and values, so I'm not getting why I cannot get the array field, while getting the others like doc.data().admin is working properly.
This is my code:
export const updatePlayers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = req.body;
    const roomsRef = db.collection("rooms");
    const snapshot = await roomsRef.where("roomId", "==", data.roomId).get();
    const player = req.body.player;
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log("No matching documents.", data.roomId);
      res.status(201).send();
      return;
    }
    console.log("updating players...");

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const prevPlayers = doc.data().players;
      console.log(doc.data().players, "previous players");
      const newPlayers = [...prevPlayers, player];
      console.log(newPlayers, "new players");
      doc.ref.update({
        players: newPlayers,
      });
      res.status(200).send();
      console.log("players update");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};

Do you see any issue in the method? How should I get that field?


Apart from the use of Promise.all that Ilya Andreyev indicates in his answer there isn't any error in your code at first sight. doc.data().players; should return the array. Difficult to say more...

@RenaudTarnec I think the same, not sure why it's not returning the array. With code proposed in Ilya Andreyev answer I'm having the same issue..

You could try with a brand new collection just to be sure there isn’t any "hidden problem"…

Nightmare issue: I didn't realise that players field was initialised with name "players:", so containing that colon...

Try this version:
export const updatePlayers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = req.body;
    const roomsRef = db.collection("rooms");
    const snapshot = await roomsRef.where("roomId", "==", data.roomId).get();
    const player = req.body.player;
    
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log("No matching documents.", data.roomId);
      res.status(201).send();
      return;
    }

    console.log("updating players...");
    let updatePromises = [];

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const docData = doc.data();
      console.log("Document data:", docData);
      
      if (!docData.hasOwnProperty('players')) {
        console.log("Players field does not exist in document.");
        res.status(400).send("Players field not found.");
        return;
      }

      const prevPlayers = Array.isArray(docData.players) ? docData.players : [];
      const newPlayers = [...prevPlayers, player];
      console.log("previous players:", prevPlayers);
      console.log("new players:", newPlayers);

      updatePromises.push(doc.ref.update({
        players: newPlayers,
      }));
    });

    await Promise.all(updatePromises);
    res.status(200).send();
    console.log("players update");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};


This code is also working but I get same issue, that in this case is "Player field not found". Not sure why I'm not able to get it..

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
